# Populating D3 Graph with Cartodb

Tags: carto, jquery, d3

I have been looking at D3 and following along with their basic tutorials. In the documentation you can use json files to create graphs, however I am confused on how to make the connection from my cartodb query,  to the input of D3. To clarify I have made a successful query to my cartodb table and returned those results from there I need make a connection from my returned json query to D3.

```
  var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'ceigis' });
sql.execute("SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM deldot_rail_crossing GROUP BY status")
  .done(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.total_rows; i++) {
      $('#content').append("<div><span>" + data.rows[i].status + "</span><span>" +  data.rows[i].count+ "<span></div></br>"); ///This was just to test if my json query was correct 
     //Making the Connection from my query to D3 is where I am struggling 

        d3.json("data.json", function(json) {
```

I am ultimately trying to create a simple pie graph of how many records fall within 4 different statuses.

**UPDATE**: I was able to get a working pie chart. One of my problems was passing json object instead of an array.code posted below.. hope this helps out others

```
function init(){
var w = 1000;
var h = 1000;
var r = 200;
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c"]);

var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'igis' });
sql.execute("SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM rail_ing GROUP BY status")
        .done(function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.total_rows; i++) {
                var data = data.rows;
            }       
        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        var group= canvas.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(300,300)");


        var arc = d3.svg.arc()           
            .outerRadius(r)
            .innerRadius(0);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()         
            .value(function(d) { return d.count; });

        var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d",arc)
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return color (d.data.status); });

        arcs.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" +  
                    arc.centroid(d) + ")";})
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", "1em")
            .text (function (d) {return d.data.status;});

        });   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After you have done the request you already have the `data` so you don't need to use `d3.json`, just feed the `data` to a selection and work with that.

On **d3** you can [bind data to a selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) (usually  `data` is a javascript array, in this case could be `data.rows`), and then use that `data` to create your pie graph as in [this example](https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1203641).

So something like:

```
var piechart = d3.select("#my_pie_chart") // Id of the block you want to use to show your data
    .append("svg:svg")               
    .data(data.rows)                         // Bind the data you already have to the selection                   
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    ...                                   // Draw the pie chart...
```

Comment: I was way off track thank you for pointing me in the right direction however I am running into problems with accessing the data. I think there is a problem with how d3 is reading the array.                                                        I am getting a error of ( Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'map')

Answer (score -1):

specifically for the d3js pie charts, data( **[** data.rows **]** ) might solve your problem

Comment: Ya I have posted a complete code example <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792051/d3-pie-chart-json-structure-issue">Here</a> Still not working

Comment: Are you able to expand upon your Answer to perhaps explain why you think it may be applicable?  Normally "about a paragraph" is treated as being minimum length for Answers (and Questions here).

Comment: (just seeeing this now) my comment is no longer relevant as the source code has been updated. but the original issue was that the asker was passing a single element to a method that needed an array. That element should be turned into an array (even an array of one) for the method to work.